# i couldn't call ajax on chrome while using xampp

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xampp

my files are in C:/xampp/htdocs directory.

i want to call

```
{"name":"john", "age":19.4}
```

file from

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_json() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "jsp.js", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            var results = document.getElementById("results");
            results.innerHtml = data.name;
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

file.

when i click html file it just write "requesting..." then it should call ajax but it doesn't do it. actually i'm sure that all codes are true cause i wrote them while watching an ajax tutorial and i checked my codes nearly 100 times. where i went wrong everytime?all other people who also watched the tutorial says they achieved it.

note:i think there is something wrong about how(.html, .js) and where(isn't C:/xampp/htdocs correct directory) should i save my files?

Comment: Are you getting errors in your browser console?

Comment: what browser? and can you post your htdocs directory contents?

Comment: @lonesomeday it's just write "requesting..." but in tutorial "requesting..." change to "john" immediately. basically it's doesn't call ajax

Comment: @jibsales   chrome and firefox..... same mistake on both of them directory C:/xampp/htdocs/xxx(the file i created)

Comment: is `jsp.js` your JSON data and is it located in the root of htdocs?

Comment: @user2783998 Yes, indeed. Your browser console may have some errors that shed light on what's going wrong.

Comment: One thing you might consider: it's not necessary to set `Content-Type`, since you aren't sending any data. You could remove that line. I don't think it will make a difference, however.

Comment: How are you accessing the file? If you are using a file:// url rather than http://localhost or some domain pointed to 127.0.0.1 then this will fail

Comment: @jibsales jsp.js my json it's rigth but where is root of htdocs(i didn't get it) there is a xxx file in htdocs as i wrote and my .js and .html files are in it

Comment: @RobM. firstly i run xampp(apache and mysql) then i'll write localhost/180 and i click my json.html file to call jsp.js file but nothing happeinng. that's what i see http://localhost:180/xxx/json.html

Comment: @lonesomeday I think the content-type plays here... he is loading a `.js` file when it should be `.json`

Comment: @RobM. i told you how i run my files on xampp. i run it from    **Index of /xxx**

[ICO] Name Last modified Size Description
[PARENTDIR] **Parent Directory**    -  
 
[TXT] json.html 2013-12-06 00:51 694  
[   ] jsp.js 2013-12-06 00:51  27  
                                       once i read ajax can't call from here it can be true

Comment: @jibsales That won't make a difference. The OP is setting the `Content-Type` header of the *request*, i.e. telling the server what is being sent, not what he expects the server to send in reply.

Comment: @lonesomeday good call... confused it with "accepts" header, though I feel MIME type plays a roll still @user2783998 try renaming your `jsp.js` file to `jsp.json` and change the url in the javascript code as well to reflect the change

Comment: @user2783998 I see, I've answered your question below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results.innerHTML = data.name;` not `results.innerHtml = data.name;` Javascript is case-sensitive

Comment: Thanks! I think I read it around 20 times before I noticed. :P

Comment: i really gave two days for this thing. actually this is better than something wrong with windows or chrome.thank you for all